# Find the function $f(x)$ knowing the volumen of the solid of revolution for $a \gt 1$

Tags: calculus, solid-of-revolution

Find the function $f(x)$ knowing that the volumen of the solid of revolution of $y=f(x)$ around the x axis, for $a \gt 1$ is $V=a^2 -a$ , $f(x)$ continuos and $ f(x) \gt 0$

Basically what I tried to do was use the mean value theorem for integrals by doing:

$$V=\pi\int_{0}^{a} (f(x))^2 dx = a^2 -a = a(a-1)$$

$$V=\int_{0}^{a} (f(x))^2 dx = \frac{a(a-1)}{\pi}$$

Then, by the Mean Value Theorem for Integral

$$\int_{0}^{a} (f(x))^2 dx =  f(c)(a-0) = f(c)a = \frac{a(a-1)}{\pi}$$

and so we have that

$$(f(c))^2 = \frac{(a-1)}{\pi}$$ and

$$(f(c)) = \sqrt{\frac{(a-1)}{\pi}}$$

Is this the way to do it? Anyways, I'm stuck here. Any Hints? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differentiate both sides with respect to $a$ (using the FTC):
$$\pi(f(a))^2=\frac{d}{da}(a^2-a)=2a-1$$
so, since $f(x)>0$ for all $x$,  $$f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2x-1}{\pi}}.$$

Comment: This was my initial thought, but since a is a value and not a variable I thought that I couldn't use the FTC

Comment: Well, it's not, is it? is actually a variable, I think.

Comment: The volume is given as a function of $a$, so we may differentiate the two expressions for the volume with respect to $a$. You can also verify that this function $f$ is correct by putting it back into the integral at the start.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I was confused by that, now I see. Thanks

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)